# read api url from separate file in angular

Tags: angular

Is it possible to create a text file where API URL's will be there.
So if any api url changes, then just need to change that file url and no need of changing the url in the service and then making build again for the production environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `environment files` for this, Here is a good article for this

https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be

Here in official angular documentation you can find more details about it

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#the-src-folder

They have defined `environments` folder as -

*This folder contains one file for each of your destination environments, each exporting simple configuration variables to use in your application. The files are replaced on-the-fly when you build your app. You might use a different API endpoint for development than you do for production or maybe different analytics tokens. You might even use some mock services. Either way, the CLI has you covered.*

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @Aravind ohh, I have added more content on it :)

Comment: yeah after adding it you will have to build.

Comment: sadly this is what I want to prevent :)

Comment: if you will add any element or change any value in your code then you have to build every time otherwise it will be `undefined`